# Is equaling a variable to another creates a duplicate or it is just makes actions over existing one?

Tags: php

I am not sure if I could explained properly but I am going to try describe better.

I have too much lines of code and to make my code readable, I am parsing the parts that is not always using and I am including them when need it.

One of these includes is an extension for importing files;

```
((isset($session) && $session) && isset($file)) || die('You do not have permission to access this file.');


$fileExt = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!($fileExt == 'txt' || $fileExt == 'csv')) {
  $importer = 'EXT_ERROR';
} else {

}
```

It is not done but when it is, going to import some data to my app.

I am calling it like this when need it;

```
if(isset($_FILE['import_file'])) {
  $passImporter = array(
    'file' => $_FILES['import_recipients'],
    'session' => $sessionControl,
    'handler' => $mailingLists,
    'theme' => $theme
  );

  $mp->loadExtension('importer', $passImporter);
}
```

loadExtension() function basically passes the required variables to the importer and calls it;

```
function loadExtension($extension, $extractions) {
    extract($extractions);
    include_once __DIR__.'/extensions/extension.'.$extension.'.php';
 }
```

My question is, equaling $mailingLists, $theme and other variables to other variables and passing them to the included file, does it put an extra load on my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable takes a part of your system memory. Usually, it's completely insignificant. However, it depends on your application - what sort of calculations and processing it does, how many requests per minute you have, how much data it returns.

I would advice to solve such optimization problems when they appear, as they rarely make any impact.

In your case, as I understood, you are concern about reassigning values to the same variables. Actually, it's even more effective as you use the same part of memory and erase old data.

Recommendations:

The easiest way to check the time and memory required is to use `microtime()` and `memory_get_usage()` functions.

Put the output of `microtime()` before a piece of code you want to test and after it, then find the difference. The result is the time required for the operation in microseconds.

Do the same with `memory_get_usage()`.